# Django NameError: name 'model' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I am altering an existing application so I can expand the use case a bit. I have already created a new model and altered the view and template a bit. Now I want to run migrations, but I keep getting the NameError and a Google search didn't provide me with much more information, especially since I am adding things to a working application rather than creating something from scratch. Is anyone able to help me?

I have added the following line to admin.py:
admin.site.register(InputData)

the error:

```
C:\var\www\SYSTEM>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 120, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\var\www\SYSTEM\System\service_development\admin.py", line 201, in <module>
    admin.site.register(InputData)
NameError: name 'InputData' is not defined
```

EDIT:
I have solved it myself. Turns out there was an 'init' file where all models had to be referenced in order to use them in Admin.

Comment: The content of `C:\var\www\SYSTEM\System\service_development\admin.py` would be very helpful. Probably you don't import `InputData`.

Comment: There is nothing Django-specific about this really. You're using a variable 'InputData' that doesn't exist, probably because it should have been imported but wasn't. Just simple Python.

Comment: It can be missing import or cyclical import. Is seems that simple missing import

Comment: I have already an import in place: from .models import * but that still doesn't seem to work. As I mentioned before, it is a fully working app without my additions (meaning the import of the other classes works fine, it is only ImportData that is troubling.

Comment: solved it for yourself - what did you change? Would have been nice if you had just supplied an answer that showed 'before' and 'after' - rather than 'there is an 'init' file ... and I changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last two lines of your error give me the idea that you might have forgotten to import 'InputData' class in admin.py file.

```
File "C:\var\www\SYSTEM\System\service_development\admin.py", line 201, in <module>
    admin.site.register(InputData)
NameError: name 'InputData' is not defined
```

Import 'InputData' class in admin.py and you are good to go :)

Comment: Like so from .models import *? Because this works for all other classes except this one.

Comment: @Natasja Can you provide the code of your admin.py file and the 'InputData' class so I can know what exactly is going on?

Answer (score 5):

This most likely means that you are not importing "InputData" in your admin.py file.